# Inject IEnumerable<IInputFormatters>

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I've a hard time trying to inject `IEnumerable<IInputFormatters>` to other services.
I've registered my own `InputFromatter` and also I've added `JsonFormatters`. So, at least there should be 3 input formatters, but when I try to inject `IEnumerable<IInputFormatters>`, I'm constantly getting `null` (like there is no formatters at all).
My registration looks like:

```
services.AddMvcCore(config =>
            {
                config.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new UserContextFormatter());
                config.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new ModelBinderProvider());
            })
                .AddAuthorization()
                .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>())
                .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
                {
                    opt.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                    opt.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                    opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                })
                .AddJsonFormatters()
                .AddApiExplorer();
```

Seems like something easy and stupid, but I'm not good enough to get it. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `IEnumerable<IInputFormatters>`, it is not registered as service, so you could not resolve it or access it from Dependency injection.

For `InputFormatters` or `ModelBinderProviders`, they are appended to `Action<MvcOptions> setupAction`, so you could access them from `IOptions<MvcOptions>`.

Try code below:

```
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MvcOptions _options;
    public HomeController(IOptions<MvcOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
        var inputFormatters = _options.InputFormatters;
        var outputFormatters = _options.OutputFormatters;
        var modelBinderProviders = _options.ModelBinderProviders;
    }
```